# How to implement multiple instance in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

In my application, I have  third party printers. When i print some document using that printers,it will invoke and pass an argument to apple script. From that apple script , i am launching my cocoa app with that argument. 
Like this:

```
on run argv
    do shell script ("open -n /Applications/PrintApp.app/ --args " & "'" & item 1 of argv & "' ")
end run
```

Then i will capture the argument in my cocoa app to do my business logic. But the problem is, when i give multiple prints using that third party printers, it will launch my PrintApp every time.

I don't want my app to be launched multiple times. Because i can't able to handle the previously opened apps. But i need to pass the argument to my cocoa app when print job is done.

Can any one provide the solution to handle this problem? or how can i implement multiple instance to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

Passing command line args to an application is only possible when launching it. You have to find another way of passing new "jobs" or whatever to your application; you could, for examplem create a socket and talk to that. Or you could write the new arguments to a file which is being watched by the main application.